# Finding Matrix inverse using SIMPLEX Method

Tags: matrix-inverse

How can we find inverse of a matrix using Simplex method? Do we need to have square matrix only or inverse can be found of any matrix? Also specify about the upper bound on the matrix size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Matrix Inverse is required during simplex only over the Basis Matrix (Basis Inversion).
Base matrix is a square matrix of dimensions (mxm) where m is the total number of constraints.

This Matrix Inversion is carried out using either the Product form of Inverse or LU Decomposition.